# "Had I not had cash" or "Had I not have"

Tags: grammar, tense, subjunctives

I want to know, what is the correct form grammatically.

> Had I not had cash on me, I would have been in deep trouble

or

> Had I not have cash on me, I would have been in deep trouble.

Is this a less used form & perhaps, something like the following?

> Did I not have cash on me, I would have been in deep trouble

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a form of the subjunctive, and is quite uncommon.

This form of the subjunctive is formed by inverting the subject and auxiliary verb "had" *in the past perfect*. So the first word must be "had" and the main verb must be in the past participle form. It is easier to follow if the main verb isn't a form of "have"

> Had I seen the boat, I would have waved.

Using the basic form of the verb is not grammatically correct

> *(Had I see the boat...)

Using "have" forms a question, not a subjunctive:

> Have I seen the boat?

The "had" subjunctive is a rare feature of English. You can nearly always replace it with an "if":

> If I'd seen the boat...

So in your example, the only possible form is:

> Had I not had cash on me...

The others are either ungrammatical  *(had I not have cash), or are a question (did I not have cash?)

But you could say:

> If I hadn't had cash...